# Serialize nullable decimal numbers in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, decimal, nullable

I'm a modest C# programmer in one of the world top insurance companies. I recently recompiled a huge software with .Net framework 4.0.
This is a very large business ASP.Net application containing many thousands of objects;  It uses serialization/deserialization in memory with MemoryStream to clone the state of the application (insurance contracts) and pass it on to other modules and to save it at the end.
It worked fine for years. Now sometimes, not systematically, BinaryFormatter.serialize throws the exception
Decimal byte array constructor requires an array of length four containing valid decimal bytes.
After a patient search I identified the field responsible, it is declared as follows:

```
     public class myClass  
     {  
     .......

     private decimal? uidStampa = null;  
     public decimal? UIDStampa  
     {  
        get  
        {  
           if (uidStampa == null)  
           {  
              uidStampa = Convert.ToDecimal(strdoc.Substring(5));  
           }  
           return uidStampa;  
        }  
        set  
        {  
           uidStampa = value;  
           decimal d = (decimal)uidStampa; // NO Complaint  
           d.SanityCheck("_idstampa set"); //my method to check bits of the decimal  
        }  
    }  
    .........  
}
```

and it is initialized through the setter as
myClass.UIDStampa = id; this id is a plain decimal number

Sometimes for reasons yet to be discovered, this id  apparently has a valid value: 
If I go over it or with quickwatch I see the value  20000499428,
while if I examine it closer it is formed by
20000499428 = {00000168  00000000  00000004  A81F66E4}
So the fourth number, the scale one, is invalid though it does not effect the decimal point of the decimal. No complaints until serialization.  Only the serializer complaints.

If I declare the private variable as NOT NULLABLE but plain decimal as
private decimal uidStampa = 0M;
the error is swallowed, I mean it remains with the fourth number invalid, but it looks like it is not considered.

The questions are:
Why BinaryFormatter.Serialize behaves differently if the private variable is declared nullable or not and the public one is still nullable ?
The serializer of .Net 3.5 behaves differently ?
To discover the root of the evil, so the point where the invalid value is set, what could be a tool to check memory in C# ?

I'll appreciate any suggestion

Marco